# Basic C++ memory question

Tags: c++, opengl

a friend of mine declared a new type using

```
typedef GLfloat vec3_t[3];
```

and later used vec3_t to allocate memory

```
vertices=new vec3_t[num_xyz* num_frames];
```

He freed the memory using

```
delete [] vertices;
```

**Question:**
**1.** Since vec3_t is an alias for GLfloat[3], does it mean that

```
vec3_t[num_xyz* num_frames]
```

is equivalent to

```
GLfloat[3][num_xyz* num_frames];
```

**2.** If the above is a 2 dimentional array, How is it supporsed to be properly deleted from memory?

thanks in advance;
 from deo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.** a  two dimensional array can be thoght  of as a one dimensional array  where each element is an array.
using this definition you can see that  `new vec3_t[num_xyz* num_frames]`  is equivalent to a two dimensional array.

**2.** this array is made of `num_xyz* num_frames`  members each taking a space of `sizeof (vec3_t)`
when `new` is carried out it allocates `num_xyz* num_frames` memory blokes in the heap,  it takes note of this number so that when calling `delete[]` it will know how many blocks of `sizeof (vec3_t)`  it should mark as free in the heap.

Answer (score 3):

`GLfloat` is an array that is "statically" allocated and thus that doesn't need to be explicitly deallocated.

From a memory point of view, this `typedef` is equivalent to the following structure:

```
typedef struct {
  GLfloat f1;
  GLfloat f2;
  GLfloat f3;
} vec3_t;
```

You can then have the following code which is now less confusing:

```
vec3_t* vertices = new vec3_t [num_xyz* num_frames];
[...]
delete[] vertices;
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be deleted the same way it's been allocated - one contiguous piece of memory.

See [2D array memory layout](http://fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/23two-dim-array-memory-layout.html)

Comment: this not entirely correct there is a difference between allocation an array and allocating a single object.  that's  why  you have delete vs delete[]

Comment: The visualization in the first example of your link is misleading - ttt is defined as an array, not as a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it right,

```
vec3_t[num_xyz* num_frames]
```

is equivalent to

```
GLfloat[num_xyz* num_frames][3]
```

Since you allocated with `new[]`, you have to delete with `delete[]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the delete is OK, but to reduce confusion I tend to do this:

```
struct vec3_t{
  GLFloat elems[3];
};

vec3_t* vertices = new vec3_t[num_xyz* num_frames];
```

Now you can see the type of `vertices` and:

```
delete [] vertices;
```

is obviously correct.